# box2d world :: everything is so light !

Tags: iphone, box2d-iphone

i'm using box2d 2.1.2 with cocos2d 0.99.4

in my world, everything is light, 
there is no sensation about dropping a stone or a box !!
everything falling slowly at the same speed

> ```
> b2Vec2 gravity; 
> gravity.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);
> bool doSleep = true;
> world = new b2World(gravity, doSleep);
> ```

and my objects :

```
b2BodyDef *TBodyDef = new b2BodyDef;
    TBodyDef->position.Set(100, 200);
    b2Body *TBody = world->CreateBody(TBodyDef);
    TBody->SetType(b2_dynamicBody);
    TBody->SetAwake(true);
    b2CircleShape TCircleShape;
    TCircleShape.m_radius = 20;
    b2FixtureDef TFixtureDef;
    TFixtureDef.shape = &TCircleShape;
    TFixtureDef.friction = 0.1;
    TFixtureDef.density = 0.1;
    TFixtureDef.restitution = 1;
    TFixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = COLLISION_BIT_GP;
    TFixtureDef.filter.maskBits = COLLISION_BIT_TERRAIN;
    TBody->CreateFixture(&TFixtureDef);

    b2BodyDef *TBodyDef1 = new b2BodyDef;
    TBodyDef1->position.Set(200, 200);
    b2Body *TBody1 = world->CreateBody(TBodyDef1);
    TBody1->SetType(b2_dynamicBody);
    TBody1->SetAwake(true);
    b2CircleShape TCircleShape1;
    TCircleShape1.m_radius = 20;
    b2FixtureDef TFixtureDef1;
    TFixtureDef1.shape = &TCircleShape;
    TFixtureDef1.friction = 0.1;
    TFixtureDef1.density = 0.5;
    TFixtureDef1.restitution = 1;
    TFixtureDef1.filter.categoryBits = COLLISION_BIT_GP;
    TFixtureDef1.filter.maskBits = COLLISION_BIT_TERRAIN;
    TBody1->CreateFixture(&TFixtureDef1);
```

and my step :

```
int32 velocityIterations = 8;
int32 positionIterations = 3;

world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
```

density changes nothing about the speed of falling.
what is missing to make it as fluid as this : 
[link text](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/04/29/following-a-body-with-the-camera-in-box2d/#more-2813)

thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

An objects density does not affect the speed it falls at.

Negating air-resistance and other generally negligible effects all objects DO fall at the same speed.

How to test this: Pick up something light (e.g. your friends iPhone 4) and something heavy (your old CRT) and drop them out of a window at exactly the same time.

Comment: you mean that at the surface of moon, one kg of cotton falling down at the same speed that one kg of steel ??

Comment: Yes, that is true. I don't have anything more to add.

Comment: hehe ok  :=)

if i add to this function a more iteration, it would be more fluid
but is it a correct way to do it ??

-(void) tick:(ccTime)dt
{
 int32 velocityIterations = 8;
 int32 positionIterations = 3;
 for (int32 i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  
 {
  world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
  world->ClearForces();
 }
 
}

Comment: but i preferred your first answer before changing ti to this one  :=)

Comment: I don't know why that would be more fluid since you are doing more calculations a frame...it might be best to ask on the box2D forum.

Comment: well indeed, you are right, in fact it is not changing the distance my ball is covering when launched, hmmm i'm waiting for approval from box2d administrator :=) anyway thank you for your help :=)

Comment: finally, got my problem, it was because my bodies were huge, i did not used PTM_RATIO, oufff  :=)