# cocos2d box2d: different mass but body fall at same time

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have created 2 box2d body with cocos2d sprite....they have different mass and they fall from same place in the world. but they fall ground at the same time. my idea is that the lighter body should fall later then the heavier one.....but they didn't.

```
for (int k=1;k<=2; k++) {
    int idx = (CCRANDOM_0_1() > .5 ? 0:1);
    int idy = (CCRANDOM_0_1() > .5 ? 0:1);
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithBatchNode:batch rect:CGRectMake(32 * idx,32 * idy,32,32)];
    [batch addChild:sprite];

    sprite.position = ccp( p.x+(32*k), p.y);


    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

    bodyDef.position.Set(( p.x+(32*k))/PTM_RATIO, p.y/PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.userData = sprite;

    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);


    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(.5f, .5f);//These are mid points for our 1m box


    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox; 
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f/k;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
    NSLog(@"%f",body->GetMass());
}
```

Comment: Possibility of duplicate [box2d world :: everything is so light !!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905315/box2d-world-everything-is-so-light/3905414#3905414). "An objects density does not affect the speed it falls at."

Comment: In a frictionless environment, weight does not affect acceleration. The reason a feather falls slower than a rock, on earth, is that we have an atmosphere. Without that (in Box2d and on the moon), a rock and a feather fall at the same speed.

Comment: @nash and @Kazuki Sakamoto: Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, Galileo Galilei discovered that all objects drop with the same speed...

https://web.archive.org/web/20100728100438/http://galitzin.mines.edu/INTROGP/notes_template.jsp?url=GRAV%2FNOTES%2Ffallb.html&page=Gravity%3A%20Notes%3A%20Falling%20Bodies

Answer (score 0):

You could set a different damping on these bodies.

Experiment with differente values. 0 means no damping but the max value is not limited so beware.